# How to get frame of a view and set it to gradient's frame

Tags: ios, swift

all I have a page control with some specified anchors as below. I want to apply a gradient to its background. But I am unable to get the page control's actual frame. Can anybody help me.

this is the page control's frame which is working fine.

```
pageControl.setAnchor(top: nil, bottom: buttonsContainerView.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor);
        pageControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true;
```

Calling function to apply the gradient to the page control.

```
addGradientForPageControl(view: pageControl);
```

The page control code

```
lazy var pageControl: UIPageControl = {
        let pc = UIPageControl();
        pc.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black;
        pc.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white;
        pc.numberOfPages = self.pages.count;
        pc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        pc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePageClick), for: .touchUpInside);
        return pc;
    }();
```

Gradient function.

```
func addGradientForPageControl(view: UIView){
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer();
        gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height);
        print(Int(view.layer.borderWidth));
        let topColor = UIColor(red: 107/255, green: 143/255, blue: 133/255, alpha: 1).cgColor;
        let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 68/255, green: 126/255, blue: 114/255, alpha: 1).cgColor;
        gradient.colors = [topColor, bottomColor];
        view.layer.addSublayer(gradient);
    }
```

if I call the above function, I always get the gradient's frame to be (0,0,0,0). This causes no gradient on the background. Is there any way to get the frame of the page control by calling like view.widthAnchor.something to get the frame width and height.

Comment: Where are you calling `addGradientForPageControl`? You are probably calling it somewhere that runs before the pageControl's frame is set.

Comment: Layers don't auto-resize along with the view. You need to manually resize the layer when the view size changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably adding gradient before the view is assigned a frame and laid out on the screen. Try adding the gradient in viewDidLayoutSubviews() method.